# How can I bind fields to knockout in an Editor Template in MVC4?

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

In my MVC4 project I have a Category view model with a collection of Product view models. I use an Editor Template to render a single Product view model, and pass the collection of Product view models to it:

Category view model:

```
@model CategoryViewModel
@using MVC4PartialViews.Models.ViewModels

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
</div>

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Products)
```

Editor template that renders each Product in the collection:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
</div>
// etc.
```

This works very well as it automagically names and indexes the elements correctly so all the Products get posted back as part of the parent Category view model - here's what it outputs:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Products_0__ProductName" name="Products[0].ProductName" type="text" value="Add 1st product for this Category" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Products[0].ProductName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

How can I bind fields in the Editor template to knockout? Can I somehow access or use the index value that the editor template uses to name the elements? I can bind fields no problem in the parent (Category) view model as below:

```
<script>
    window.defaultCategory = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>

@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.CategoryName,
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"style", "width: 30%;"},
        {"placeholder", "Please enter the Category name"},
        { "data-bind", "value: currentCategory.CategoryName" }
    })
```

I would need to produce something like this where [n] is the index value produced by the Editor Template as it renders each Product in the Products collection:

```
{ "data-bind", "value: currentCategory.Products[n].ProductName" }
```

Or should it be like this:

```
{ "data-bind", "value: currentCategory.Products()[n].ProductName" }
```

All help or ideas appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the current index from the TemplateInfo:

```
@model ProductViewModel

<div class="editor-field">    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        model => model.ProductName,
        new {
            style = "width: 30%;",
            placeholder = "Please enter the Category name",
            data_bind = string.Format(
                "value: currentCategory.{0}.ProductName",
                ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
            )
        }
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Not familiar with ViewData.TemplateInfo need to read up on it.